# the cc and bcc is not working i cant send it through one of them

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient(My.Settings.smtpserver)
        mail.From = New MailAddress(My.Settings.from)
        mail.[To].Add(My.Settings.destination)
        mail.Subject = "Program"
        mail.Body = "Hi this is a msg form .net application"

        Dim path As String = My.Settings.desktop
        Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(path)
        Dim filesInDirectory As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()
        Dim attach As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
        For Each file In filesInDirectory
            attach = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file.FullName)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
        Next

        SmtpServer.Port = My.Settings.port
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New 
System.Net.NetworkCredential(My.Settings.username, My.Settings.password)
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Sent Successfuly!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Send!")

        mail.CC.Add(My.Settings.CC)
        mail.Bcc.Add(My.Settings.BCC)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed Sending Email!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Failed!")
    End Try
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

End Class

the cc and bcc is not working i cant send through cc nor bcc is there any problem with my codes? the user can use this cc and bcc like gmail.

Comment: your code looks fine, put a breaker point on the mail.cc and view what my.settings.cc has in it

Comment: what do you mean breaker?

Comment: and the cc and bcc is blank in my.settings.cc

Comment: If those settings are blank then why would you expect something to be added to the mail message?

Comment: Even if cc and bcc are not blank, adding them after the MailMessage has been sent is not going to be productive.

Comment: because the user will add it

Answer (score 1):

Well - you are setting CC and BCC after you send the email. Thats your problem.  Move the lines:

```
    mail.CC.Add(My.Settings.CC)
    mail.Bcc.Add(My.Settings.BCC)
```

Up to where you are setting Mail.Subject, etc.

Comment: i put it at the top of subject under destination but still didn't work

Comment: Well - that means you have an additional problem.  But setting the cc and bcc AFTER you send certainly will never work.